# Extracting comments from article using disqus

Tags: python, web-scraping, disqus

I am pretty new to webscraping and would like to extract comments made on a web article which uses a disqus thread, using python. I think I have to use the DisqusAPI to do this and import it into python, however I am not understanding how it works.

Would anyone be able to give me some guidelines as to what I should do or how to use the disqus api through some example?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used disqus before. And I am learning webscrapying via python too.
Scarpy may also be a choice for you, and you may check the turorial for scrapy here.
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html